# maxent RJava situation 1001

Tags: java, r, rjava, maxent

Ive been struggling with overcomming a series of errors for using the function `maxent` in the `dismo` package.

`Loading required package: rJava
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
running command '/usr/libexec/java_home' had status 1`

Ive tried:
1- updating my R version 
2- removing and reinstalling the latest Java version 
3- removing and reinstalling rJava 
4- Installing JGR

None have solved the issue. Any help out there?

Comment: Do you have to set environment variables such as JAVA_HOME or JDK_HOME or JRE_HOME in order for rJava to find the Java stuff? Just guessing; I haven't used rJava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the Terminal console execute:

```
machine-name:~ username$ which java
/usr/bin/java
machine-:~ username$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Since I have the jre installed I can go into R and run:

```
> library(rJava)
> help(pac=rJava)
> res <- .jinit(classpath="myClasses.jar", parameters="-Xmx512m")
> res
[1] 0    # the sign of a successful initiation
```

You should be displaying similar information as below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats4    grDevices utils     datasets  graphics  stats    
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rJava_0.9-8         MASS_7.3-47         copula_0.999-16   
  snipped the rest of my loaded package listing
```

I never had any success working with JGR so cannot help on that  aspect.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but still no go. The second I try to install rJava and load it I come back to the same error

Comment: IT likely has something to do with me having MacOS Sierra

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... to me, this worked:

- Uninstall your java and install again, but make sure to install the 64bit version.
- Then, install the packages

  install.packages("rJava");
  install.packages("dismo")
- here: http://biodiversityinformatics.amnh.org/open_source/maxent/ you download maxent... then paste the "maxent.jar" file in the 'java' folder of the 'dismo' package. You have to do this **before** loading the libraries. You find the directory of yor 'dismo' package running the following:

  system.file("java", package="dismo")
- In your system, open the regedit.You will have to create a Prefs key in the JavaSoft folder. In mine, it's here: Computador\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft  ... Depending on your system, it may be here: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft
  ...so, take a look, and asure yourself to create Prefs in the right directory. Then:
- Right button click in JavaSoft > New > Key > name the key as Prefs. it is supposed to work now. Load the libraries and try it.